# Crypto++ Code::blocks Undefined reference problem

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, codeblocks, crypto++

I'm trying to create a C++ program using Crypto++ (with Code::Blocks), but keep getting stuck with the same problem. I'm using a cut-down version of this code : http://andreyvitdev.blogspot.com/2005/10/crypto-usage-sample.html
, but I can't get it to compile.

```
#include "cryptopp/blowfish.h"
#include "cryptopp/osrng.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    byte key[Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH],
            iv[Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE];

    AutoSeededRandomPool rng (true);
    rng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof (key));
    rng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof (iv));

}
```

I get multiple errors, starting with : "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Programming\C++\CodeBlocks\Crytp tester\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to `CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator::GenerateBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned int)'"

Am I missing something? There are many references on different sites to libraries that must be imported, but I couldn't figure out where they were in the crypto++ folder : http://www.cryptopp.com/#download

Comment: Looks like you forget to link the library. Check how to specify libraries to link to in Code::Blocks and add `cryptopp`.

Comment: +1 for including a minimal, complete sample program. For more information about why this is important, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a good look around, but where exaxtly would the cryptopp library be found?

Answer (score 5):

"Undefined reference" is a linker error -- either you didn't build the Crypto++ library, or didn't tell the linker to link to it.

I'm not positive if it will build using MinGW (the most common compiler with Code Blocks) though. The Microsoft compilers (along with Visual Studio) are free; and are tested explicitly with both Code::Blocks and Crypto++.

Comment: I'm using the GNU GCC compiler with codeblocks, should I choose a different one?

Comment: @Kalessar: GCC does not run on Windows. There's either MinGW (which contains a (bad) port of GCC to Windows), or running GCC inside of Cygwin. GCC is a great compiler for UNIX platforms, but on Windows MinGW really stinks. (It can't build native x64 binaries, for instance)